# Can we call an activity with code in Kotlin UNIT TEST

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

I am just starting with kotlin test and i wanted to know if it is possible to launch an activity with some code. For exemple, i have my MainActivity and a second activity. Is it possible to call the second activity in order to make unit test on it?

Comment: More details would be helpful..
What do you want to test?

Comment: I have a lot of textview on the second activity and i want to check wich one is display because i'm not display all of them

Comment: Can you explain your question properly? Without proper explanation no one can help you..

Comment: i am writting some kotlin test and i just want to know if there is a way to launch something similar to startactivity but for unit test

Comment: A possible option would have been "Robolectric", although I've never seen it actually work, despite having tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am making an assumption that you want to write Espresso tests. In that case, you do not need to start a new activity, simply initiating the new activity from the UI will launch the new activity.

Comment: yes i think that you answered my question. But i am still a beginer so may be you can explain me how to do that :)

Comment: Espresso tests are really behavioral tests, ie, you use them to test if your UI follows a given set of behavior. As a result, it is more geared to your interaction with your UI, than the logic to launch new activities. In fact, espresso does not provide such login, the only thing you can do is add a wait to your code while the activity is launched by your interaction, then the espresso test picks up

Answer (score 0):

if you want to navigate MainActivity to second activity your can write the following code on button click listener and on over events

```
                val intent = Intent(this,RecyclerViewDemo::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: startActivity does not work in test. I want something like this but for test